# I am having issues with NameValuePair being deprecated. It's Android Studio 1.3. and API 23.Is there libraries I can import for this?

Tags: android-support-library

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
```

Answer (score 0):

In `android.support.v4.util` package there's a class `Pair<F,S>` which is probably what you are looking for.

But I highly recommend you to create your own class to keep key-value objects and extend its functionality as you like (for example, implement Parcelable interface)